# What is "socket + 1" achieving when making a select call? unix/c++

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, select, udp

I am implementing a udp listen server based on this https://linux.m2osw.com/c-implementation-udp-clientserver. I noticed when establishing a timeout receiver the author included "f_socket+1" when making the select call. I am wondering what exactly this is doing? Any explanation helpful, thank you!

excerpt of function from above link:

```
    FD_ZERO(&s);
    FD_SET(f_socket, &s);
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = max_wait_ms / 1000;
    timeout.tv_usec = (max_wait_ms % 1000) * 1000;
    int retval = select(f_socket + 1, &s, &s, &s, &timeout);
```

Comment: Probably an array of sockets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/select.html

> The *nfds* argument specifies the range of file descriptors to be tested. The *select()* function tests file descriptors in the range of 0 to *nfds*-1.

Thus, that argument should be set to 1 greater than the maximum file descriptor you want to monitor.

Comment: FYI, `(e)poll()` is generally preferred over `select()`, then you don't have to worry about this, since `(e)poll()` is given an array of *specific* socket descriptors to work with, it doesn't have to deal with *ranges* of descriptors.